# Open file in different position cause different result

Tags: c

The test1.c:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        FILE* fp = fopen("test.txt","rw");
        int n,m,q;
        scanf(" %d%d%d",&n,&m,&q);
        struct test_t test;
        while (fscanf(fp,"%d%s%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%*d",&test.line,test.data,&test.number[0],&test.number[1],&test.number[2],&test.number[3],&test.number[4],&test.number[5],&test.number[6])!=EOF) {
                //do something.....
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

The test2.c:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int n,m,q;
    scanf(" %d%d%d",&n,&m,&q);
    struct test_t test;
    FILE* fp = fopen("test.txt","rw");
    while (fscanf(fp,"%d%s%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%*d",&test.line,test.data,&test.number[0],&test.number[1],&test.number[2],&test.number[3],&test.number[4],&test.number[5],&test.number[6])!=EOF) {
            //do something....
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The definition of test_t:

```
struct test_t {
    int line;
    char* data;
    int number[7];
};
```

My test.txt:

```
141 2015-12-05 19 16 35 06 34 46 09 00
124 2015-12-08 49 25 10 09 40 48 32 00
143 2015-12-10 09 29 24 47 32 34 42 00
```

When I use test1.c I got **segmentation fault**.But when I use test2.c, it works well.Only change the line of `FILE* fp = fopen("test.txt","rw");`.What cause this difference.

Comment: Your code does not compile as the size of `size_t` isn't known by the compiler.

Comment: @AshishAhuja I didn't post the definition of `test_t`,I will post it now

Comment: Why didn't you post it? Always post code that compiles!

Comment: What is the expected input and output? What do you enter? What is the output? Please post that.

Comment: @AshishAhuja The problem is not what I want to get.The problem is why I change the position of `FILE* fp = fopen("test.txt","rw")` will cause different result.

Comment: when doing a "gcc -pedantic" you will get a warning like "ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code" for test1.c

Comment: `fopen("test.txt","rw")` does not do what you expect.  If you really need to open the file in update mode, use `"r+"`.

Comment: @ice_city, check if the place you are running the program has the file where you are reading and writing from. Try the error checking mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are invoking UB as you never allocate memory for `char* data;`. Fixes:

1. `malloc` enough memory before the `while` loop:

   ```
   test.data = malloc(32);
   if(!test.data)
   {
       fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed...Bailing out!\n");
       exit(-1);
   }
   ```

   And after its use,

   ```
   free(test.data);
   ```
2. Use an array of predefined size instead of a pointer to `char`:

   ```
   char data[32];
   ```

---

Also, as [@AshishAhuja said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35389711/3049655), check the return value of `fopen` also.

Answer (score 2):

Well, when you run the program from a different place, there are high chances that the file does not exist in that place. Thus, check if `fopen` returns `NULL`. Do this:

```
FILE* fp = fopen("test.txt","rw");
if (fp == NULL) {
   printf ("Error, file does not exist\n");
   exit (1);
}
```

Opening a file that does not exist is not a problem, as `fopen` will just return `NULL`. Trying to read or write in it will cause a Segmentation Fault and also a Core Dump.

---

Also, you are never allocating memory for `char *data`, which might cause the problem. To allocate and free properly, see [@CoolGuy's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3049655/cool-guy) answer.

Comment: worse than that: `test.data` is uninitialized: passing it as the receiver for `scanf` `%s` format definitely invokes undefined behavior. Initializing to to allocates memory is one possible solution.